# Excel show data with IF conditionals?

Tags: excel, formulas

Anyone know the formula to achieve the following:

Say I have a spreadsheet of inventory, and I'd like to determine the price of an item that has the following properties: color, size.

So let's say our companies trucks on row A, have a corresponding COLOR on row B, and a poundage value on row C. And finally, on row D there's a price for it

Now what I'd like to do is a formula that identifies all cars with COLOR red and POUNDAGE 1000, and averages out the price of these types of trucks.
I know a bit about excel formulas, it probabaly is going to have two IF conditionals, then an average identifier, and a sum function. I'm just not THAT good at it.

Ex of my data https://www.flickr.com/photos/77598212@N03/34635594150/in/dateposted-public/

So the ideal would be. For ex, if for row A shape is "cu" and row B weight is 1.7, gather those prices for those items found in row K, average those prices, and spit out The result. Lot of steps lol

Any thoughts? Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Look into the SUMIFS Statement along with the typical if statement:

=SUMIFS(sum range, criteria range 1, criteria 1, criteria range 2, criteria 2, ect)

If you take a screen shot of your data source it would be easier for us to help

Comment: Krunch thanks for the response. Illl look into that. Here's what my data looks like https://www.flickr.com/photos/77598212@N03/34635594150/in/dateposted-public/

Comment: So the ideal would be. For ex, if for row A shape is "cu" and row B weight is 1.7, gather those prices for those items found in row K, average those prices, and spit out The result. Lot of steps lol

Comment: @Masteryogurt For the average you could do a sumif divided by a countif